# Reputation by post doesn't seem to work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On the reputation page, I don't see any difference between "by post" and "by time". It is grouped only by time also when selecting "by post".

[image: By post?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a bug. What you're seeing *is* sorted, but it has a preference for sorting day first.

**"by post"** sorts:

- by day,
- and then grouped by post

**"by time"** sorts:

- by day,
- by individual timestamp